# How to make a nice legend for a histogram with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I am trying to make a histogram with the fitted curve plotted on it. Here's the mwe:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
    \usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{2pt}
    \newcommand{\plots}{0.611201}
    \newcommand{\plotm}{2.19882}
    \begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
    2 0.0629921259843
    3 0.0236220472441
    4 0.0314960629921
    5 0.125984251969
    6 0.0629921259843
    7 0.102362204724
    8 0.110236220472
    9 0.0551181102362
    10 0.0629921259843
    11 0.0314960629921
    12 0.0236220472441
    13 0.0314960629921
    14 0.0629921259843
    15 0.0551181102362
    16 0.0393700787402
    17 0.0472440944882
    18 0.00787401574803
    19 0.0393700787402
    24 0.00787401574803
    27 0.00787401574803
    33 0.00787401574803
    \end{filecontents}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{preview}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    scaled y ticks = false,
    minor y tick num={1},
    xtick pos=left,
    legend cell align = left,
    legend style={draw=none},
    xlabel = {group size},
    ylabel = {ratio}
    ]
    \addplot[blue,ybar,fill, fill opacity=0.3, bar width = 0.8,] table {data.dat};
    \addplot[red, line width = 1,domain=1:40,samples=100] {1/(x*sqrt(2*pi)*\plots)*exp(-(ln(x)-\plotm)^2/(2*\plots^2))};
    \legend{empirical,lognormal fit}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{preview}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the legend is not really good. How can I change the legend so it looks more like this?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of solving this. One way is to move the `ybar` option from the `\addplot` to the `axis`. The same key means slightly different things in the two locations, in the `axis` it refers to `/pgfplots/ybar`, while in the `\addplot` it refers to `/tikz/ybar`. It would appear that these lead to different behaviours for the legends, though I have not looked at precisely how they're defined.

Of course, when you add `ybar` to the `axis`, it will affect all `\addplot`s, so you must also add `sharp plot` to the line plot. `sharp plot` is the default style for `addplot`, it draws a line with markers by default.

Result and complete code first, second option below:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\newcommand{\plots}{0.611201}
\newcommand{\plotm}{2.19882}
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
2 0.0629921259843
3 0.0236220472441
4 0.0314960629921
5 0.125984251969
6 0.0629921259843
7 0.102362204724
8 0.110236220472
9 0.0551181102362
10 0.0629921259843
11 0.0314960629921
12 0.0236220472441
13 0.0314960629921
14 0.0629921259843
15 0.0551181102362
16 0.0393700787402
17 0.0472440944882
18 0.00787401574803
19 0.0393700787402
24 0.00787401574803
27 0.00787401574803
33 0.00787401574803
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
scaled y ticks = false,
minor y tick num={1},
xtick pos=left,
legend cell align = left,
legend style={draw=none},
xlabel = {group size},
ylabel = {ratio},
ybar
]
\addplot[blue,ybar,fill, fill opacity=0.3, bar width = 0.8] table {data.dat};
\addplot[sharp plot,red, line width = 1,domain=1:40,samples=100,line legend] {1/(x*sqrt(2*pi)*\plots)*exp(-(ln(x)-\plotm)^2/(2*\plots^2))};
\legend{empirical,lognormal fit}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Second option

Another way is to simply add `area legend` to the options of the `\addplot` command for the `ybar` plot. This tells `pgfplots` to create a filled rectangle as the legend entry, instead of just a line, as in the prefered example. You can also use `ybar legend` instead of `area legend`, which will make it like in the first example. You can find the definitions of how the legend entries are created in the manual.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\newcommand{\plots}{0.611201}
\newcommand{\plotm}{2.19882}
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
2 0.0629921259843
3 0.0236220472441
4 0.0314960629921
5 0.125984251969
6 0.0629921259843
7 0.102362204724
8 0.110236220472
9 0.0551181102362
10 0.0629921259843
11 0.0314960629921
12 0.0236220472441
13 0.0314960629921
14 0.0629921259843
15 0.0551181102362
16 0.0393700787402
17 0.0472440944882
18 0.00787401574803
19 0.0393700787402
24 0.00787401574803
27 0.00787401574803
33 0.00787401574803
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
scaled y ticks = false,
minor y tick num={1},
xtick pos=left,
legend cell align = left,
legend style={draw=none},
xlabel = {group size},
ylabel = {ratio}
]
\addplot[blue,ybar,fill, fill opacity=0.3, bar width = 0.8,area legend] table {data.dat};
\addplot[red, line width = 1,domain=1:40,samples=100] {1/(x*sqrt(2*pi)*\plots)*exp(-(ln(x)-\plotm)^2/(2*\plots^2))};
\legend{empirical,lognormal fit}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Third option (dealing with alignment issues)

As can be seen, in the first option, the legend for the histogram is misaligned. We can fix this by overriding the default behavior of `ybar legend`. The default behavior (see manual) is

```
\pgfplotsset{
/pgfplots/xbar legend/.style={
/pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
\draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,bar width=3pt,yshift=-0.2em,bar shift=0pt]
plot coordinates {(0cm,0.8em) (2*\pgfplotbarwidth,0.6em)};},
},
}
```

Here's an example with the complete code for a much nicer looking `ybar legend`

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\newcommand{\plots}{0.611201}
\newcommand{\plotm}{2.19882}
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
2 0.0629921259843
3 0.0236220472441
4 0.0314960629921
5 0.125984251969
6 0.0629921259843
7 0.102362204724
8 0.110236220472
9 0.0551181102362
10 0.0629921259843
11 0.0314960629921
12 0.0236220472441
13 0.0314960629921
14 0.0629921259843
15 0.0551181102362
16 0.0393700787402
17 0.0472440944882
18 0.00787401574803
19 0.0393700787402
24 0.00787401574803
27 0.00787401574803
33 0.00787401574803
\end{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{
/pgfplots/ybar legend/.style={
/pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
\draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,bar width=0.1cm,yshift=-0.2em,bar shift=0.5*\pgfplotbarwidth]
plot coordinates {(0.5*\pgfplotbarwidth,0.6em) (2.5*\pgfplotbarwidth,0.4em) (4.5*\pgfplotbarwidth,0.2em)};},
}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
scaled y ticks = false,
minor y tick num={1},
xtick pos=left,
legend cell align = left,
legend style={draw=none},
xlabel = {group size},
ylabel = {ratio}
]
\addplot[blue,ybar,fill, fill opacity=0.3, bar width = 0.8,ybar legend] table {data.dat};
\addplot[red, line width = 1,domain=1:40,samples=100] {1/(x*sqrt(2*pi)*\plots)*exp(-(ln(x)-\plotm)^2/(2*\plots^2))};
\legend{empirical,lognormal fit}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: could you explain the original behaviour and why your solution is necessary to fix it?

Comment: @ArTourter No. I don't know why `pgfplots` doesn't default to `area legend` for the `ybar` plot.

Comment: do you know what it defaults to? it is rather weird!

Comment: @ArTourter I updated my answer.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks! This kind of looks like a bug then. Anyway, I would disagree, that the first version looks better, since the histogram legend and the line legend are seriously missaligned. Three columns, with the tallest being as tall as the text and centered so it is aligned with the line would be better than the second though. I'm looking at how to do just that, although that might come up as a new question :D

Comment: @fbence You're right about the misalignment, I didn't notice that they're a bit off. Not sure if it's a bug, if you think so report it at SourceForge. http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgfplots/

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. I found that specifying the `bar width` causes the problem.

Comment: Here's the bugreport: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/88/

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I edited your answer with `ybar legend` option and a suggested way to fix the misalignment issue.

Comment: @fbence Yep, I noticed. Great!