# pgfplots: Shared legend for two axis

Tags: pgfplots

My plot has two axis, one with a bar chart, the other with two line charts.
I want a shared legend for all the charts now. I'm quite before the target, but the symbol for LegendS becomes a striped line - and not "minibars". How to fix that? I'm also open for other solutions without a matrix.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
      \begin{axis}[
              axis y line=left, 
              axis x line=bottom,
              enlarge x limits=0.1, 
              enlarge y limits=0.08, 
              ylabel={Label Y1},
              xlabel={LabelX},
              symbolic x coords={1,2,3,4,5,6},
              xtick=data,
              legend columns=-1,
          ]            
          \addplot [ybar,draw=brown!80!black,fill=brown!20] coordinates {(1,93) (2,59.36) (3,48.43) (4,43.16) (5,39.96) (6,38.1)};
          \label{pgfplots:plot1}
      \end{axis}
      \begin{axis}[
              axis y line=right,
              axis x line=none,
              enlarge x limits=0.1, 
              ylabel={Lavel Y2},
              xtick=data,
          ]

          \addplot coordinates {(1,0) (2,2212) (3,2453) (4,2677) (5,2872) (6,2895)};
          \label{pgfplots:plot2}

          \addplot coordinates {(1,0) (2,1726) (3,2238) (4,2513) (5,2641) (6,2756)};    
          \label{pgfplots:plot3}
      \end{axis}

      \matrix[
          matrix of nodes,
          anchor=north west,
          draw,
          inner sep=0.2em,
          column 1/.style={nodes={anchor=center}},
          column 2/.style={nodes={anchor=west},font=\strut},
          draw
      ]
      at([xshift=-1.1cm,yshift=-1.1cm]current axis.south){
          \ref{pgfplots:plot1}& LegendS\\
          \ref{pgfplots:plot2}& LegendA\\
          \ref{pgfplots:plot3}& LegendB\\};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252418/how-to-make-a-nice-legend-for-a-histogram-with-pgfplots/252445#252445

Comment: This link has nothing to do with my case. There is always just one axis.
Difficult thing. I would set a bounty but I can't, yet...

Comment: Of course it has something to do with your case. The problem there was that the `ybar` legend showed up as a line legend, which is exactly the same problem that you have. The first option I mentioned in my answer there was to move `ybar` from the `\addplot` options to the `axis` options. The second was to add either `area legend` or `ybar legend` to the `\addplot` options in addition to `ybar`. Both those solve your problem.

Comment: oh. you are right, I'm very sorry! The first option works, great. Didn't thought that this will work at all, when there is one more axis.